# GWT: How to add DockLayoutPanel inside another panel? Not the RootLayoutPanel

Tags: gwt, gwt2, docklayoutpanel

Is it possible to add DockLayoutPanel inside another panel other than the RootLayoutPanel?
If so, how would you do it?
I attempted to add it inside HTMLPanel, and only north of the DockLayoutPanel shows.
Then I tried it inside LayoutPanel, it failed again.

I thought it would have work for LayoutPanel because RootLayoutPanel is a subclass of LayoutPanel.

Any answers welcome.
Thanks,

Comment: is it giving you an error, or is just nothing shouwin up on the screen?

Comment: Hi Stefan, there was no error, but only the north panel is displaying.

Thanks to Thomas Broyer, I figure it out now. It was because HTMLPanel does not implement ProvidesResize and I did not explicitly set the size of the DockLayoutPanel, so it was only displaying the north panel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DockLayoutPanel` is a `RequiresResize` widget, so either you put it inside a `ProvidesResize` widget (any so called *layout panel*) or you give it an explicit size.

See the *Using a LayoutPanel without RootLayoutPanel* section in http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels.html#Recipes

Comment: I have a layout with DockLayoutPanel where center has HTMLPanel as a container for contents. The content however is also a DockLayoutPanel defined in UiBinder of another view class. How do I add that programmatically? I can add other contents just fine, but for DockLayoutPanel, only the north panel is displaying.

Comment: HTMLPanel cannot ProvidesResize for the inner DockLayoutPanel, so you have to explicitly set the size of that panel.