# GWT ScrollPanel not visible

Tags: gwt, user-interface, docklayoutpanel

I have a DockLayoutPanel in my ui.xml class. When I wrap it in a ScrollPanel the whole thing disappears.
Any ideas?

Comment: Put the DockLayoutPanel inside a LayoutPanel:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/8780498/1930604


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8780498/1930604

Answer (score 0):

DockLayoutPanel seems to need to be included inside a SimplePanel to be used in some Components,  but a ScrollPanel should be a type of SimplePanel.  Have you explicitly set the size of the DockLayoutPanel?  Or tried embedding it in a SimplePanel?

Answer (score 0):

Is a fixed pixel size set on the DockLayoutPanel? if not it will just try to wrap to 0x0px since this is the size calculated for it.

alternatively you can set the size of the DockLayoutPanel to 100x100% so it has the size of the scroll panel. However this will make the scroll panel pretty useless (size the content has it's size so scrollbars are never visible).

if you are trying to let the DockLayoutPanel have a larger size depended on the content of the DockLayoutPanel, this also won't work since each area of the DockLayoutPanel has a fixed size or takes the remaining size.

hope this helps, if not provide us a more detail description what you are trying to do?

Regards,
Stefan